# Can WAMP and Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants be installed on same computer?

Tags: wordpress, wamp, vagrant, localserver

Can WAMP and Vagrant be installed on the same computer or is it best to uninstall WAMP if I want to try VVV?

I know it is not a good idea to install XAMPP and WAMP on the same computer and when I do a search about VVV and WAMP, my search results only return info on xampp/wamp. Additionally, I have read several VVV install tutorials and none mention uninstalling any other local servers already installed on the computer.

I am trying to setup a development/test/production environment on my computer and want to follow the best practices/methods so I can get up and running the right way.

It seems Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants is the ideal local server for WordPress theme development and what I will mainly be working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Vagrant is a virtual machine running inside it's own environment, I don't think it will collide with WAMP. I'm no Windows user, but on my Mac i'm also running MAMP and Vagrant at the same time without any problems.

Comment: Thanks. This confirms a similar reply from the WP forums. I'm still working on setting up VVV; I keep running into issues! I'll get it eventually, crossing fingers.